# Should this work to trigger a webhook in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, html, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to trigger a webhook in Google Tag Manager. I have a variable loaded and confirmed working via Tag Assistant.

[tag assistant showing variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNgXd.png)

I'm trying to trigger a webhook and pass along this Custom Variable.

I have a Custom HTML tag with this javascript:

```html
<script>
  fetch('https://hook.us1.make.com/28c815lw998s1o6ab37e3il7uw957p7g?record_id={{AirtableRecordID}}');
  </script>
```

But it doesn't seem to be hitting the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I would concatenate it like so:

```js
fetch('https://hook.us1.make.com/28c815lw998s1o6ab37e3il7uw957p7g?record_id=' + {{AirtableRecordID}});
```

Also, you can always open your network tab and debug this fetch.